# How to get the PHAsset that just saved using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum?

Tags: ios, swift

I use UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum to save a photo to the Photo Library:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(my_img, nil, nil, nil);
```

And on completion I want to get the PHAsset of this photo in order to change its creationDate. How can I get this PHAsset?

I have read [Get PHAsset/localIdentifier of image saved to photo library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65545089/get-phasset-localidentifier-of-image-saved-to-photo-library), but it doesn't seem to help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that SO is not a code writing service. Please edit your question and show what you have tried and the issues you are facing.

Comment: Dear @LeoDabus , I have absolutely no idea how to get this PHAsset, what code can I write?

Comment: @mczmma - can you confirm your image is being saved to the Photos Library ? Maybe you can start by sharing the code you wrote to save the photo and maybe someone can assist from there.